# How to use Swiper slideTo() in Vue3.0?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, swiper.js

Vue version:3.0.2

Swiper version:6.3.5

I'd like to use Swiper's slideTo method in Vue3.0, but it doesn't seem to work.

Can you tell me how to use it? https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-hooks-1jblc?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You seem to be using one library but referring to the other for documentations.

- https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper (official)
- https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-awesome-swiper

You are importing the library from `swiper/vue`, so it has to be the official one; in which case, there is a slight difference in accessing the Swiper instance: You need to **store the Swiper instance**. (see [Controller mode](https://swiperjs.com/vue/#controller)). So in your case:

```js
<template>
  <swiper
    style="border: 1px solid red; width: 400px"
    :slides-per-view="1"
    @swiper="onSwiper"
  >
    <swiper-slide>Slide 1</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 2</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 3</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 4</swiper-slide>
  </swiper>

  <button @click="handleSlideTo">slide to 4</button>
</template>

<script>
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/vue";
import "swiper/swiper-bundle.css";

export default {
  name: "App",
  
  components: {
    Swiper,
    SwiperSlide,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      swiper: null,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    onSwiper(swiper) {
      this.swiper = swiper;
    },

    handleSlideTo() {
      this.swiper.slideTo(3);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Not to be confused with [the use of `ref`](https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-awesome-swiper#difference-with-usage) by the other library (`vue-awesome-swiper`).

Comment: This should be in the official documentation! Couldn't figure out how to init my swiper as child component.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using `<script setup>`, you can do it like this:

```html
<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue'

  import 'swiper/css'

  const swiperInstance = ref()

  function onSwiper(swiper) {
    swiperInstance.value = swiper
  }

  function goToSlide(position) {
    swiperInstance?.slideTo(position)
  }
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="goToSlide(3)">
    Go to slide 3
  </button>

  <Swiper @swiper="onSwiper">
    <SwiperSlide v-for="i in 4">
      Slide {{ i }}
    </SwiperSlide>
  </Swiper>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<template>
  <button @click="slideToIndex(3)">
    Go to slide 3
  </button>

  <Swiper @swiper="onSwiper">
    <SwiperSlide v-for="i in 4">
      Slide {{ i }}
    </SwiperSlide>
  </Swiper>
</template>
<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue'
  import 'swiper/css'

  const swiperInstance = ref()

  onSwiper = (swiper) =>{
    swiperInstance.value = swiper
  }

  slideToIndex = (index) =>{
    swiperInstance.value.slideTo(index)
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation